# Facebook Login not retrieving "username"

Tags: ios, facebook

My code below will not pull the user.username from the log in.  I tried the Facebook sdk hello Facebook too and it still doesn't grab the user.username.  The strange part is that it used to at one point.  Part of my code is below.  Please advise.

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    // here we use helper properties of FBGraphUser to dot-through to first_name and
    // id properties of the json response from the server; alternatively we could use
    // NSDictionary methods such as objectForKey to get values from the my json object
    self.labelFirstName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@!", user.first_name];
    // setting the profileID property of the FBProfilePictureView instance
    // causes the control to fetch and display the profile picture for the user
    self.profilePic.profileID = user.id;
    self.loggedInUser = user;
    FitGoalAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FitGoalAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.uname = nil;
    appDelegate.uname = user;
    appDelegate.lastname = user.last_name;
    appDelegate.firstname = user.first_name;
    NSLog(@"First Name=%@",appDelegate.firstname);
    NSLog(@"Last Name=%@",appDelegate.lastname);
    NSLog(@"Real Userbame %@",user.username);
    NSLog(@"Copied Userbame %@",appDelegate.uname.username);
}
```

Comment: Are you using API v2.0? username is not available in v2.0

Comment: I am not sure.  How do I check which API I am using?  what is another option to have a unique 'username'?  user.id? @WizKid

Comment: Yes user id is unique. If you app was created after 4/30/2014 you are using v2.0.

Comment: Thanks!  This is a dumb question but what API are you referring to?  The Facebook sdk? @WizKid

Comment: No. The API version. You can find the changelog here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Oh cool thanks!  Good thing I caught the null username.  Where can I mark this question ANSWERED? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Username is not available in Facebook API v2.0

Answer (score 0):

but there's a trick you can use. After receiving the id you can make a call like this https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id} you will get the metadata of the user containing username.